# Change className after mapping a list React.js

Tags: reactjs, class, state

I need some help with a class componenent in React .

I'm tring to change the class of the li after mapping the array 'list'  .
Could you please tell  me how can I use the state in this case .
When I click on the

the className should be equal to  'active'.
I'm trying to use the state but I don't know how to make it .

I can do this without mapping the list vut i dont' want to repeat the code for each Composant .

Thank you very much for your help and I hope i will be understood

```
const list = ['Biographie', 'CV', 'Blog'];
    
    class Navbar extends Component {
      state = {
        Biographie: true,
        CV: false,
        Blog: false,
      };
    
      show = (e) => {
        list.map(item=> this.setState ({ [item]: false}))   
        this.setState({ [e.target.id]: true });
      };
    
      render() {
                   
        return (
          <div className="navbar">
            <ul className="list">
              {list.map((item) => (
                <li
                  onClick={this.show}
                  id={item}
                  className={this.state ? 'active' : ''} // How can I change class when state = true ?
                >
                  {' '}
                  {item}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <Biographie info={this.state.Biographie} />
            <CV info={this.state.CV} />
            <Blog info={this.state.Blog} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to have state as Object? If not, then simplify, let's have state only as string...

`state = null`

`const show = (e) => { this.setState(e.target.id) }`

...

`className={this.state === item ? 'active' : ''}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the id in state inside `show`,

you can do

```
className={this.state[item]  ? 'active' : ''}
```

If you are planing on having only one active element, I suggest that you use something like this instead

```
  state = {
    active:"Biographie"
  };
```

and

```
{list.map((item) => (
  <li
    onClick={()=>setState({active:"item"})}
    id={item}
    className={this.state.active === item ? 'active' : ''}
  >
    {item}
  </li>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access your state's properties using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

```js
{list.map((item) => (
    <li
        onClick={this.show}
        id={item}
        className={this.state[item] ? 'active' : ''}
    >
        {' '}
        {item}
    </li>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answer . It is much better know :)

Thanks to you I manage to show the component but there is probably a better way Once again I repeat myself and I don't like it :) .

My code below :

```
{this.state.active === 'Biographie' && 
    <Biographie />} 
    {this.state.active === 'CV' && 
    <CV info={this.state.active} />}
    {this.state.active === 'Blog' && 
    <Blog info={this.state.active} /> }
```